# Git merge doesn't report merge conflict and picks unexpected end result

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a nice reproduction script for a scenario in which GIT gives me an unexpected result:

```
# in an empty directory
git init

echo 4 > a.txt
git add a.txt
git commit -m "initial commit"

git checkout -b test
echo 6 > a.txt
git commit -am "4 => 6"

git checkout -b release master
git merge --no-edit --no-ff test

git checkout master
echo 6 > a.txt
git commit -am "4 => 6"
echo 4 > a.txt
git commit -am "6 => 4"

git checkout release
git merge --no-edit master
```

Before the last merge a.txt contains 6 and master:a.txt changed it to 4. After merging master, a.txt still contains 6! Why? I expected to see a merge conflict since both branches made changes on the same location.

I know the script may seem concocted and doesn't show use of best of practices. Please focus on why GIT produces the, for me, unexpected result.

Thanks!

Comment: Newer question for basically the same problem, and useful new answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67605145/3216427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just reproduced your scenario and found the explanation. What happens is that Git looks at only three commits to do the merge, not the intervening history.

Just before the last merge, if you do

```
MERGE_BASE=`git merge-base master release`
git diff $MERGE_BASE master
```

you will see no changes reported, since you made a change and undid it on the next commit.

When the three-way merge algorithm compares `$MERGE_BASE`, `master` and `release`, it sees that `master` did not introduce any changes and therefore accepts the changes in `release` without conflict.

Comment: Thanks. Clear. I'm guessing there's no way around this, that there's no merge strategy that does take the entire history into account?

Comment: It's not a merge strategy, but a sequence of rebase or cherry picks would walk the full history. I don't particularly recommend this approach, but I used it when I had to merge two branches that had diverged for two years. Git merge was impractical because I just couldn't figure out what to keep. So I cherry-picked all 600 commits from one branch onto the other. 10% or so had conflicts, and Git helped me resolve them one at a time. At the very end I used a trivial merge to clearly mark what I had done. It was painful but it did the job.