# What is a git conflict and in which conditions could you have a git conflict?

Tags: git

On the master branch I have a file(let's called it file.txt) which uses the fields of a structure with the old names(let's called them : old_field1, old_field2 and old_field3). On my development branch I have the same file, but another version of it which uses the same fields, but with different names(let's called them : new_field1, new_field2 and new_field3)

I merged the master branch into my development branch and I had a git conflict due to the different names of those fields. I fixed it by keeping the new names.
Later on I merged the development branch into the master branch and I had the same git conflict.

My questions are :

1. Why did I have the same conflict if I fixed it? How should I avoid
   it in the future?
2. What is a git conflict?
3. How does the 'merge' process work ? (e.g. : it applies patches in a certain order etc)

Comment: Could you share more details about your branches ? Was the dev branch checked out from master? Was other branches merged to master before you tried to merge master onto your dev ?

Comment: Yes, my development branch was checked out from master and for sure other branches were merged to master.

Comment: Here is a useful tutorial on git merge conflicts: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts

Comment: And here is a question on this site on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920885/what-constitutes-a-merge-conflict-in-git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What constitutes a merge conflict in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920885/what-constitutes-a-merge-conflict-in-git)

Comment: Finally, I wrote up an answer on explaining unexpected merge results in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54481842/3216427

Answer (score 2):

You're starting from a fairly bad place in your question, or maybe chose a particularly unlucky example, as shown by #3 here:

> How does the 'merge' process work ? (e.g. : it applies patches in a certain order etc)

because `git merge` does not (quite) apply patches.  But you want to know what makes a conflict occur, so you need to understand a lot of things about Git.

#### Commits are snapshots, plus a bit more

First, let's look as briefly as possible at *commits*.  You already know that to make *new* commits, you `git checkout` a branch, do some work on it, `git add`, and `git commit`.  You may or may not know, though, that each commit holds a *full and complete snapshot* of **all** of your files.

This might seem odd, given that `git show` shows a commit as a *patch* or *change-set*, and `git log -p` shows each a patch for each commit.<sup>1</sup>  But that's because a commit doesn't *just* store a snapshot.  If you run `git log`, with or without `-p`, you get more information for each commit.  For instance:

```
$ git log | head -7 | sed 's/@/ /'
commit 7c20df84bd21ec0215358381844274fa10515017
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
Date:   Fri Aug 2 13:12:24 2019 -0700

    Git 2.23-rc1

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

So a commit stores not only the snapshot, but also some name and email address stuff and so on.

Note the big ugly hash ID, `7c20df84bd21ec0215358381844274fa10515017`.  This is, in effect, the true name of the commit.  This one particular commit will *always* be `7c20df84bd21ec0215358381844274fa10515017`.  It will be `7c20df84bd21ec0215358381844274fa10515017` in *my* clone of this Git repo, and in *your* clone of this same repo (https://github.com/git/git), and in the GitHub clone, and in the Git peoples' clones, and so on.  We can also look directly at the raw contents of this commit:

```
$ git cat-file -p 7c20df84bd21ec0215358381844274fa10515017 | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 8858576e734aa4f1cd9b45e207e7ee2937488d13
parent 14fe4af084071803ab4f16e6841ff64ba7351071
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1564776744 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1564776744 -0700

Git 2.23-rc1

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

That's actually the entire internal Git commit *object*, right there: the snapshot is held indirectly, through the first line that says `tree` and has another big ugly hash ID.  The rest of the lines—`parent`, `author`, `committer`, and the log message that Junio Hamano typed in when he made this commit, make up the rest of this commit.

Note closely the `parent` line.  This has another big ugly hash ID.  You can look at that commit directly if you like: clone the repository and `git cat-file -p` that hash ID.  You'll see that this one has another `tree` line—that's this other commit's snapshot—and more `parent` and `author` and so on lines.  This next commit—which is really the *previous* commit—actually has *two* `parent` lines, because commit `14fe4af084071803ab4f16e6841ff64ba7351071` is a *merge commit*.

These various `parent` lines string commits together, by their hash IDs, in *backwards* order.  Each commit has a true-name hash ID, and each commit has some number of `parent` lines.<sup>2</sup>  Most commits have exactly one of these lines.  That one line give the hash ID—the true name—of the commit's parent commit.

Once a commit is made, it is frozen forever.  So it's impossible to reach back up into the parent and *add* the hash ID of the child, when you later make a new child commit.  That's why each commit only knows its parents: they exist at the time the commit is born, and as soon as the commit is born, it's frozen for all time.  The commit gets its hash ID *by* being born, and the uniqueness of the hash ID is determined in part by the *time*, down to the second, that you make the commit (encoded into those `author` and `committer` lines—the date and time stamp on the one shown above is `1564776744 -0700`, for both author and committer).

Note that commits, and their snapshots, are frozen forever.  We can't get any work done with frozen stuff!  So Git gives us a work area—a place that Git calls a *work-tree* or *working tree* or anything along these lines—where it expands out the frozen (and compressed) files from a commit.  There's also a very important thing called the *index* or *staging area* (two names for the same thing) that I won't cover here, which sits "between" the commit you checked out, and the work-tree.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that `git log -p` *doesn't* show a patch for merge commits, but `git show` does.  There's a lot more to know here but for brevity we'll skip all of this.

<sup>2</sup>At least one commit has *no* parent, as we'll see in a moment.  Most have one.  Some—merge commits—have two or more; any commit with at least two parents is by definition a merge commit.  More-than-two is rare and never, in a sense, necessary, though if you look through the Git repository for Git, you will find some. For instance, `89e4fcb0dd01b42e82b8f27f9a575111a26844df` is one such.

---

#### Commits therefore form a particular kind of *graph*

Mathematically, a *graph* is defined by a pair of sets: *G = (V, E)* (see [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#/)).  In this case *V*—the set of vertices in the graph—is all of your commits, as found by their hash IDs, and *E*—the set of edges—comes from the `parent` lines.  For the very simplest cases, though, we can just *draw* the graph, which I think is a lot more comprehensible.  Let's use one-letter names for commits, to stand in for the big ugly hash IDs, and imagine we have a tiny repository with just three commits, all in a row:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Commit `C` is the *last* one we made.  It remembers the hash ID for commit `B`, so `B` is `C`'s parent.  Meanwhile, `B` remembers the hash ID for commit `A`: `A` is `B`'s parent.  But commit `A` is the very first one we ever made, so it has *no* parent.  In Git terms, it is a *root commit*.  It has no parent because it can't have any parents: there were no commits before `A` existed.

Let's make a new commit now.  It will get some random-looking hash ID, but we'll just call it `D`.  The *parent* of `D` needs to be the commit that comes before `D`.  But that's just commit `C`, of course.  So `D`'s parent will be `C`.  The snapshot will be whatever we want it to be.  The author and committer will be us, with "now" as the time-stamp, and we get to write up a log message.  Git takes all of that stuff—the tree, the `parent` being `C`, our name and email and the times, and our log message—and writes them out as a new commit, acquiring some hash ID that we'll pretend is just `D`, and now we have:

```
A <-B <-C <-D
```

#### `git show` and `git log -p` use the graph to compare snapshots

Git can can *compare* the snapshot in `C` to the snapshot in `D`.  If we do that, we'll see what we changed.  That's what `git log` and `git show` do: given some commit, they look at the *parent* of that commit as well as at that commit.  Whatever is *different*, that's what they show as your patch.

You can also use `git diff` to compare *any two* commits.  For instance, you can compare the first commit ever, `A`, to the last one here, `D`, using `git diff hash-of-A hash-of-D`.  Git extracts both snapshots, compares them, and tells you what's *different*.

#### Branch names find commits

So far, none of this is hard at all.  Each new commit gets some big ugly random-looking hash ID.  Each commit points back to its parent.  No problem, eh?  But wait: *How do we remember the actual big ugly hash ID of the **last** commit?*  We need a place to stash that hash ID, because in a big repository we won't be able to just glance at *every* commit and *all* of their `parent` lines and so on and figure it out.  So what Git does is this: it saves the hash ID of the *last* commit—`C`, and then `D`—in a *name*.  Let's use the name `master`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

The *name* `master`, in this case, just holds the actual raw hash ID of commit `D`—the one we just made.  From `D`, Git can use its parent line to find `C`, and then use `C`'s parent to find `B`, and so on.  The action stops when Git finds `A`, which has no parent.

So a *branch name* just identifies the *last* commit in a branch.  If we make new commit `E`, Git updates `master` by writing `E`'s actual hash ID into the name `master`:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
```

and now we have five commits on `master`.  We can keep going and eventually we have eight commits, all on `master`, like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

It's still easy, isn't it?  Let's make it a little harder. :-)  Let's create a *new* branch name, `feature`.  How exactly do we do that?  Well, we ask Git to do it using `git branch` or `git checkout`.  Now, just like with `master`, Git has to store some *hash ID* into this new name.  Which hash ID should it use?  Git requires the hash ID of *some existing commit*.

Any of our eight commits, `A` through `H`, will do.  We *can* pick one, but if we *don't* pick a hash ID, Git uses the *latest* hash ID—`H`—on our current branch.  So now we have this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- feature, master
```

One very interesting thing about this is that *all eight commits are on both branches*.

Another interesting thing is: suppose we add a new commit now.  Let's call it `I`.  **Which *branch name* does Git update?**

#### Your HEAD tells your Git which branch name to update

The answer to the question at the end of the last section is where a lot of this all really starts to come together.  Git has a very special name, `HEAD`, written in all-capital letters like this.<sup>3</sup>  Normally, Git keeps `HEAD` attached to one of your branch names:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD), master
```

This indicates that we have branch `feature` checked out.  If we run `git status`, it will say `on branch feature`.  If we `git checkout master`, we'll convert this to:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- feature, master (HEAD)
```

**In both cases, the current *commit* will be commit `H`.**  But the current *branch* will change.  We have two different names for the same commit: `feature` means *commit `H`* and `master` means *commit `H`*.

But now that we're in this slightly odd looking state, let's make a new commit or two.  We'll call these `I`, and then `J`.  Git will:

- write out the tree-as-snapshot;
- add the rest of the stuff that goes into a commit: name, email, etc., and of course the all-important `parent` line as well; and
- update the *current branch name*.

So once we have made two new commits, we have:

```
             I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- feature
```

Now let's `git checkout feature` and make two more new commits, `J` and `K`.  The first step—`git checkout feature`—results in this:

```
             I--J   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

We're back on commit `H`.  Git will have changed the files in our work-tree to match commit `H`.<sup>4</sup>  Moreover, `HEAD` is now attached to `feature`, not to `master`.  So now let's make commits `K` and `L`, which will update the name `feature` this time:

```
             I--J   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

We are now in a state where we can `git merge` and—the part you care about—get *merge conflicts*.

---

<sup>3</sup>On Windows and MacOS—technically, on case-folding file systems—you can often spell it in lowercase and have it work.  However, this starts to break if you start using `git worktree add`, so it's a bad habit to fall into.  If you don't like typing four uppercase letters, consider using the `@` synonym for `HEAD`.

<sup>4</sup>Again, the index / staging-area is very important too, and there are special corner cases where Git *doesn't* update (some of) the index and work-tree, but let's ignore all of them for now.

---

#### How `git merge` works

The `git merge` command seems like magic, but in fact, it's not magic at all.  You type in:

```
git checkout master
```

which changes your view to this:

```
             I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- feature
```

The current *commit* is now `J`, so what you see in your files matches the frozen `J`.  The current *branch* is now `master`: `HEAD` is attached to the name `master`.  Note that commits `A` through `J` are all on `master`.

Now you run:

```
git merge feature
```

The name `feature` identifies commit `L`, but commits `A` through `H` *and* `K` *and* `L` are all on `feature`.

Some commits—`A` through `H`—are on *both branches*.  One of these commits is the *best common / shared commit*.  Git calls this best-common-commit the *merge base*.  In this case, it's pretty clear which commit is the best one: that's commit `H`, which comes just before the two branches diverge.  We could go further back, but why bother?  Obviously, everything in commit `H` is the same as everything in commit `H`.

Let's think for a moment about the *goal* of `git merge`.  The goal is to *combine changes*.  How do we get changes, when all we have is snapshots?  But wait—we already know how to do that!  We use `git diff`.  We can run `git diff` on *any two* snapshots, to compare them and see what changed.

We have *three* snapshots here: `H`, `J`, and `L`.  We'll need to run *two* `git diff`s.  Let's do that:

- `git diff --find-renames hash-of-H hash-of-J` will compare `H` and `J`, and tell us what changed on `master` since the common starting point `H`.
- `git diff --find-renames hash-of-H hash-of-L` will compare `H` and `L`, and tell us what changed on `feature` since the common starting point `H`.

We do not have to type in, or even find, any of these hashes ourselves.  Git does that for us.  It knows the hash ID for `J` because that's our current commit and is in the name `master`, and it knows the hash ID for `L` because that's in the name `feature`.  Git *finds* `H` on its own, using the commit graph—which is no longer just one simple backwards chain, but still not too complicated.  If we want, we can see which merge base commit(s) Git found using:<sup>5</sup>

```
git merge-base --all master feature
```

but we don't have to bother; `git merge` does all the hard work here.

Anyway, having made the two diff listings,<sup>6</sup> `git merge` can now look at them and figure out what to do:

- If you changed a file since `H`, and they didn't, use your file.
- If they changed a file since `H`, and you didn't, use their file.
- If neither of you changed the file, use any copy of the file: all three match.

Only if *both* of you changed some file, does `git merge` have to work hard.  Now `git merge` has to actually combine your two sets of changes.  Let's say both of you touched the file `README.md`:

- If you touched line 3 and they didn't, Git can use your change here.
- If they touched line 25 and you didn't, Git can use their change here.
- But if you both changed line 42, to two *different* things, Git does not know which change is right.  The result is a conflict!

When there are no conflicts, everything is easy for Git: it just combines all the changes into what amounts to (but isn't quite) one big combined patch and applies that to the copy of the file from the merge base.  The effect is to *keep your changes* and at the same time, *add their changes*.  It's all combined and all good.  Or so Git thinks, at least: what if your change on line 3 *breaks* their change on line 25?

If there *are* conflicts, though, Git leaves you with a bit of a mess.  It writes all three input file versions into the index / staging-area (which we aren't going to talk about here) and writes a bunch of conflict markers into the work-tree copy of `README.md`.  Your job becomes: *fix up the mess* and put the *right* merge into place.  The merge is sort of suspended: Git has recorded that there *is* a merge, and `git status` will tell you that you're in the middle of a merge.  But the `git merge` command has exited.  You'll start a new command later to really finish the job.

You can also get what I call *high level* conflicts.  Note the `--find-renames` in our sample `git diff` commands.  If you have renamed some files, or added or deleted files, in your changes—the `H`-vs-`J` part on `master`—and they also renamed, added, or deleted files in their changes—the `H` vs `L` part on `feature`—it's possible that these whole-file changes conflicted with each other.  In this case, `git merge` stops with a mess, leaving the files in the index as before, but often with *no* merge conflict markers in the work-tree copies of the files.  Fortunately these high level conflicts are rare, as resolving them can be a lot harder.

Once you fix everything up, your job becomes: run `git merge --continue` (if your Git isn't too old) or `git commit` (if it is).<sup>7</sup>  Git will make a new snapshot as usual, collect a log message as usual, and write out a new commit.  This new commit will have *two* parents.

If all goes well in the merge, Git will make the new commit on its own (collecting a log message as usual): you don't have to run `git merge --continue` because the merge never stopped.  Either way—conflicted or not, resolved by hand or not—this is where the merge finishes, and this is the last bit of magic, because this new merge commit will have two parents:

```
             I--J
            /    \
...--F--G--H      M   <-- master (HEAD)
            \    /
             K--L   <-- feature
```

The *first* parent is all business as usual: `M`'s first parent is `J`, the commit you were on a moment ago.  The *second* parent is the commit you merged: `L`, the tip of `feature`.  **The fact that this is a merge commit is recorded in the commit graph.**  Commit `M` has *two* parents, `J` and `L`.  A *future* `git merge` of a *future* `feature` will find a *different* merge base.

---

<sup>5</sup>The `--all` is for particularly complicated graphs, which we don't actually have here.  This means `--all` won't do anything in this case, but `git merge` uses it, just in case we *do* have a complicated graph.  If you get two hash IDs out of `git merge-base`, the merge process gets more complicated, so we'll just skip that.  If you *leave out* the `--all`, `git merge-base` picks one of the however-many merge bases there might be at (apparent) random.  But there's almost always just one merge base anyway.

<sup>6</sup>Internally, `git merge` doesn't make diff listings.  It does run the two diffs, but in a special optimized-for-merge way.  In many cases it can skip most of the file-by-file diffs entirely, and when it does need to do the actual comparing, it uses a bunch of internal data structures to find the various changed lines, rather than a textual `git diff` output.  But the *effect* is the same, it's just more efficient.

<sup>7</sup>All `git merge --continue` does is check that there is a finished merge to commit, then run `git commit`.  But this is a bit of a safety check, helping to make sure everything is the way you think it is, so it's a bit better to use `git merge --continue` even though you *could* just run `git commit`.

---

#### Merges prepare for future merges

I'm going to repeat this here because it's the source of all of your woes.  As we saw above, `git merge`:

1. computes a merge base;
2. runs (in effect) two `git diff`s;
3. combines the changes, applying those changes to the *merge base* commit;
4. commits the result, if all goes well, or makes you clean up and commit if not.

The merge base commit found in step 1 is based on the *commit graph*.  The *commit graph* in step 4 is your input to the *next* merge—the next "step 1".

When you repeatedly merge one branch into another, you get a sort of sewing stitch pattern:

```
...--o--o--o---M   <-- mainline
      \       /
       o--o--o   <-- topic
```

becomes:

```
...--o--o--o---M1----M2--P--M3   <-- mainline
      \       /     /      /
       o--o--T--o--U---o--V--o--W   <-- feature
```

where each `M` has *two* parents, one being a previous mainline commit (maybe even a previous merge) and the other being one of the commits that *was*, at the time, the *tip commit* of the feature or topic branch.

Consider what happens now if we `git checkout mainline` and then `git merge feature`.  The name `mainline` identifies commit `M3`, which has parents `P` and `V`.  The name `feature` identifies commit `W`.  The *merge base* here is the *best common commit*, but which commit is that?  Well, let's start at `W` and work backwards: we get some anonymous commit `o`, then `V`, then another anonymous commit, and so on.

If we start at `M3` and work backwards, we get *two* commits: `P` and `V`.  That's the magic of a merge commit: by having `V` as its second parent, it automatically includes commit `V` and all the earlier `topic` commits as part of the `mainline` branch.  **What this means is that commit `V` is now the merge base** and the two `git diff` commands will:

- compare `V` vs `M3`, to see what we changed, and
- compare `V` vs `W`, to see what they changed.

These are the change-sets that `git merge` will attempt to combine.  Conflicts, if there are any, occur because of overlapping changes in the two change-sets.

The *content* of a merge commit is up to you.  The *graph* of a merge commit is implied by the graph at the time you ran `git merge`.  One of the key inputs to `git merge` is the *merge base*, and Git finds this automatically, using the graph.  To *view* the graph, see [Pretty git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452).

#### Takeaways

- Commits are snapshots plus metadata.
- Some of the metadata forms the commit graph.  These are the *parent* links, which all point backwards: Git has to work backwards.
- Branch names identify one specific commit.  This one specific commit is the *last* commit of / in / on the branch.  Git calls this the *tip commit*.
- Making a new commit advances the current branch name to point to the new commit.  The branch now has a new tip.
- `HEAD` tells you which *name* is the current name, and that name then tells you which *commit* is the current commit—so `HEAD` gives Git two different pieces of information at the same time.
- "The branch" can mean *a whole series of commits, found by starting at the last commit given by the branch name and working backwards*.
- Many commits are pretty often on *many* branches simultaneously.  (See [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).)
- Working backwards through a merge commit means following *both* parents.
- `git diff` can compare any given two commits' snapshots.
- `git show` compares a commit to its parent; so does `git log -p`.
- `git merge` walks as much of the graph as it needs to, to find the *best* merge base.  It then makes *two* diffs and combines them, for a true merge.

Not part of the above, but important:

- Git makes new commits from the files stored in the *index*, not those in the work-tree.
- Since merge commits have at least *two* parents, `git show` has to do something special here (and it does), but `git log -p` is lazy and just doesn't bother to do *anything* to show a patch.  Either way, both commands leave a lot out, on purpose: "patches" for a merge are inherently kind of faulty.
- `git merge` is sometimes deliberately lazy: if a true merge isn't required, it will do a *fast-forward* instead.  When `git merge` does a fast-forward, it *doesn't* make a new commit.
- In "detached HEAD" mode, `HEAD` points directly to a commit, rather than being attached to a branch name.  Everything else works the same, except that asking Git the question: *which branch name is the current branch* comes back with *error: does not compute*.
- `git checkout` (or in Git 2.23, the new `git switch`) is how you change *which branch name* `HEAD` is attached-to.