# Unexpected behaviour when git cherry-pick and merge between branches

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I'm surprised that changes done after cherry-picking in git become obsolete when merging. Here is a full example.

The following is business as usual.

1. Create a repo
2. Add a file with test "rotums kanoner och krut"
3. Check out a new branch, and add the text line "mutors kanoner och krut"
4. Check out master and cherry-pick the commit with "mutors kanoner och krut"

```
Mac:git user1$ mkdir myrepo; cd myrepo; git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/user1/tmp/git/myrepo/.git/

Mac:myrepo user1$ echo "rotums kanoner och krut" > rotum.txt

Mac:myrepo user1$ git add rotum.txt 

Mac:myrepo user1$ git commit -m "Added file"
[master (root-commit) 1044abb] Added file
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 rotum.txt

Mac:myrepo user1$ git checkout -b mybranch
Switched to a new branch 'mybranch'

Mac:myrepo user1$ echo "mutors kanoner och krut" >> rotum.txt  

Mac:myrepo user1$ git commit -am "Added mutor"
[mybranch 19afeba] Added mutor
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

Mac:myrepo user1$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

Mac:myrepo user1$ git cherry-pick 19af
[master cce2ca5] Added mutor
 Date: Wed May 19 16:12:04 2021 +0200
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

Mac:myrepo user1$ cat rotum.txt  
rotums kanoner och krut
mutors kanoner och krut
```

Now is when the unexpected behaviour occurs.

5. I remove the line that was added and cherry-picked (I do this by overriding the file, unconventional method, but useful in this case).
6. Then I merge mybranch to master. I would expect the changes done in f63dc50, removal of a line, to remain, but it mysteriously vanishes. The line "mutors kanoner och krut" is back.

```
Mac:myrepo user1$ echo "rotums kanoner och krut" > rotum.txt  

Mac:myrepo user1$ cat rotum.txt  
rotums kanoner och krut

Mac:myrepo user1$ git commit -am "Removed mutor"
[master f63dc50] Removed mutor
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)

Mac:myrepo user1$ git merge mybranch
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 rotum.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

Mac:myrepo user1$ cat rotum.txt
rotums kanoner och krut
mutors kanoner och krut
```

Is this expected behaviour or a bug?

Comment: Similar question from a couple years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54480730/3216427

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a diagram :

```
   Initial commit: create file
   |    Add a line in file (cherry-pick b)
   |    |    Remove line, return file to its state in a.
   v    v    v
   a----c----d  <- master
    \
     b <- mybranch
     ^
     Add a line in file
```

When you merge `mybranch` into `master` :

- git looks for the closes common ancestor (aka the merge base, commit `a.` in the diagram),
- it looks at `master` (commit `d`) and sees that, when compared to `a.`, the file is left unchanged
- it looks at `mybranch` (commit `b`) and sees that, when compared to `a.`, a line should be added

so the merge succeeds without conflicts, and "brings in" the changes from `mybranch`.

---

You reach this situation because :

1. `git merge` does not inspect the intermediate commits in the history of `master` and `mybranch` ,
2. `git cherry-pick` creates new, unrelated commits, and nothing is kept in the commit graph to indicate "these changes were already included",
3. it so happens that the changes can be combined without conflicts (your example is really simple, but "no conlicts" may very well happen in actual situations).

---

To give further perspective :

- if you use `git rebase` :

```
git checkout mybranch
git rebase master
```

unlike `git merge`, `git rebase` *does* compare the list of commits, and if a rebased commit introduces the exact same changes as another commit in the target branch, that commit is dropped.

In your example : `b` wouldn't be reapplied, because it introduces the exact same changes as `c` which is already on `master`.

- if you had merged commit `b` instead of cherry-picking :

```
       merge 'mybranch'
       v
   a---c----d  <- master
    \ /
     b <- mybranch
```

then `git merge mybranch` would have said `already merged`, and wouldn't have re-applied commit `b`

Comment: Thank you both LeGEC and IMSoP for a great explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The key here is that git does not record the fact that a commit was cherry-picked from one branch to another; it just creates a new commit based on the one you specify (the same applies to "git rebase").

As far as git is concerned, you have these commits:

- 1044abb which creates the file
- 19afeba which adds the line
- cce2ca5 which adds the line
- f63dc50 which removes the line

Note that I haven't described these commits as "on" one branch or the other, because strictly that has no meaning in git; a branch points at a commit, and other commits are reachable via "parent" pointers.

At the point when you merge the two branches:

- 1044abb, cce2ca5 and f63dc50 are reachable from "master"
- 1044abb and 19afeba are reachable from "mybranch"
- the file in "master" only has one line
- the file in "mybranch" has two lines

When you merge, git determines a "merge base" based on the most recent commit reachable from both branches; in this case, that is 1044abb. It then looks at the differences between that commit and the two branches being merged:

- between 1044abb and f63dc50 ("master") the file is not changed
- between 1044abb and 19afeba ("mybranch") the file has an added line

It then combines these two changes, and applies them to produce the new version of the file. Since one side of the merge wants to add the line, and the other wants to do nothing, the resolution is to add the line.

The result is:

- cce2ca5, f63dc50 and 19afeba are all reachable from "master"
- 19afeba is reachable from "mybranch"
- you have master checked out, which has the line again

Or to put it more succinctly: you've added the line, removed it, and then added it again.

Comment: note : `git rebase` works differently : it *does* detect commits that introduce the exact same changeset, and drops them. A cherry-pick without any conflict (as in the OP case) would not get reapplied, for example

Comment: @LeGEC Yes, your answer is probably a more accurate description; after reading it, I've updated mine to remove the incorrect description of a merge happening one commit at a time.